# How do I deploy spark code from Eclipse to a Remote Cloudera Cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh

I have Eclipse Mars1 setup with Scala on my mac.
I am able to run a basic work count spark code on the local machine.
How do I run the code on a remote cluster?